# Read Android Crypto keys in php

Tags: php, android, encryption, openssl

Hi I'm writing an android app that needs crypto. On Android I generate a RSA key pair using the following code;

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
SecureRandom r=SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
kpg.initialize(2048,r);
KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
Utils.File.write(szPri,kp.getPrivate().getEncoded());
Utils.File.write(szPub,kp.getPublic().getEncoded());
```

My Utils.File creates two binary files one with the private key the other the public. I transfere the two files to my development PC for testing and basically want to use PHP to encrypt a small mesage so wrothe the following PHP code;

```
<?php

$dev="Emulator_96d68aa8156345d0";
$sz="Duncan var Her";

echo "Test Client generated key's\n";
echo $dev."\n";

$cpublic_der = file_get_contents($dev."/public");
$cprivate_der = file_get_contents($dev."/private");
$cpublic_pem = der2pem($cpublic_der);

echo $cpublic_pem."\n";

if(openssl_public_encrypt($sz,$encsz,$cpublic_pem) == true) {
    echo $sz."\n";
    echo "ok\N";
}

function der2pem($der_data) {
   $pem = chunk_split(base64_encode($der_data), 64, "\n");
   $pem = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n".$pem."-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
   return $pem;
}

?>
```

Message from php PHP Warning:  openssl_public_encrypt(): key parameter is not a valid public key

What am I doing wrong?

Duncan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` to `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` or `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----`. The same with END.